# PHP locale not working as expected on macOS

Tags: php, command-line-interface, locale, french

I'm trying to sort an array of French words alphabetically. Here's what I did:

```php
$locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');

print_r($locale);
echo PHP_EOL;

$verbs = [
    'être',
    'faire',
    'ecouter',
    'dire',
    'euphoriser',
];

sort($verbs, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);

print_r($verbs);
```

On my web server, it works as expected, printing:

```
fr_FR.UTF-8
Array
(
    [0] => dire
    [1] => ecouter
    [2] => être
    [3] => euphoriser
    [4] => faire
)
```

The accent is ignored and `ê` behaves like `e`. But there's a problem with PHP in my console on macOS. The same app prints the following result:

```
fr_FR.UTF-8
Array
(
    [0] => dire
    [1] => ecouter
    [2] => euphoriser
    [3] => faire
    [4] => être
)
```

The locale is found, because `setlocale()` returns `fr_FR.UTF-8` correctly (it returns `false` for invalid locale). But for some reason, `être` is the last element of the array after sorting. It's like this French locale is broken, or never used. How can I make my console PHP use locale correctly?

When I run `locale -a`, `fr_FR.UTF-8` is listed as one of available locales on my machine.

I'm using PHP 7.4.9.

Comment: Not sure what the issue could be here, but you could try using the [`Collator`](https://www.php.net/Collator) class in case it's better.

Comment: @Jeto the Collator, surprisingly, worked! It's weird, because even if I skip `setlocale()` and pass whatever to Collator's constructor, it still sorts correctly. I tried with `$collator = new Collator('x');` and it still works. Weird weirdness.

Comment: Yeah `Collator` is supposed to work with its injected locale, as opposed to the "global" one. Anyway, glad that worked. 

Comment: Does setting `LC_COLLATE` instead of `LC_ALL` change anything? (It really shouldn't but...)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález no, it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: @Jeto do you know how to do `ksort()` with the `Collator`? It doesn't seem to allow that.

Comment: @RoboRobok Guess you could do [something like this](https://3v4l.org/gELn7) then (you can also use your already instanced `Collator` instance if you already have one).